# cannot install gzdoom.deb on ubuntu desktop 22.10(64-bit) on raspberry pi 4

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

So I installed ubuntu 22.10. (64-bit) using the raspberry pi imager. The OS is running smooth but when I try to install the gzdoom.deb from the gzdoom page via installer, I get an error "the following packages have unmet dependencies". It does not even give me any details on this, just this textbox. Is there a way to fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35us7.jpg)

any help is appreciated

okay, I did the inistall via the console and this it what I got:

```
eehrakles@Eehrodrom:~$ sudo apt install '/home/eehrakles/Downloads/gzdoom_4.9.0a_amd64.deb' 
[sudo] password for eehrakles: 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)      
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4187 (unattended-upgr)       
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                       
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gzdoom:amd64' instead of '/home/eehrakles/Downloads/gzdoom_4.9.0a_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gzdoom:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libstdc++6:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgomp1:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: zlib1g:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libbz2-1.0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libasound2:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libogg0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libvorbis0a:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libvorbisenc2:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libflac8:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libopus0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libmpg123-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Depends: libmp3lame0:amd64 but it is not installable
                Recommends: libopenal1:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
eehrakles@Eehrodrom:~$
```

Comment: Do the install using the terminal. `sudo apt install [path-to-deb]` and paste the resulting errors into your question (do not post a screenshot)

Comment: thanks, I think I did this now.

Comment: I am not familiar with the pi, but I suspect that `amd64` package won't run on it.

Comment: would you know which gzdoom package is the right one? I also tried an armhf.deb on raspbian but had a similar issue so I thought ubuntu desktop might work better.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108360/how-can-we-run-amd64-architecture-on-a-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: thanks, I just read into this topic and I think I found the flaw. My Ubuntu is a 64 bit version but so would need an arm64 package, which does not exist. will try again with a 32bit OS and an armhf package